# nginx doesn't redirect backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, frontend, backend

I've nginx config that route frontend app to specific port, and backend to specific route

here's my configs

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.com www.test.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }

    location /api {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;           
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;                            
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  
    }
}
```

when trying to access test.com directly it works, but when trying to access test.com/api , it doesn't work, then if return to main path test.com it also doesn't work, it seems like nginx stopped working after accessing the /api

Comment: What nginx error log(/var/log/nginx/error.log) says?

Comment: @metallic
i got the following when trying to access /api

Comment: 2019/08/24 14:02:23 [error] 4055#4055: *17 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 188.161.55.XX, server: ec2-XX.compute.amazonaws.com, request: "GET /api/v1/user/quixer HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/user/quixer", host: "ec2-XX-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com"

Comment: This error implies that nginx couldn't connect to your app which supposed to be working on 3000 port. Run this command on your server and post the output: ```netstat -nutpl | grep 3000```.

Comment: actually nothing printed our, because backend isn't running at all, there was an issue in reading config file, will try to hard code the values and get back to you, thanks a lot for pointing me :D

Comment: @nabroyan i think the issue was in running the backend app, so make sure it's running successfully and staying healthy when trying to access it.